# How to set image position from Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I cant set position for an image which is used in Javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("dis").disabled = true;
var counter = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = document.createElement("img");
var y1 = document.createElement("img");
var y2 = document.createElement("img");
var xy = document.createElement("img");

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dis").disabled = false;
  counter++;
  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    if (y && xy && x) {
      y.style.display = 'none';
      xy.style.display = 'inline';
      xy.setAttribute("src", "line.png");
      xy.setAttribute("width", "75");
      xy.setAttribute("height", "3");
      xy.setAttribute("style", "margin:a b c d");
      document.body.appendChild(xy);
    }
  } else {
    xy.style.display = 'none';
    y.setAttribute("src", "circle.png");
    y.setAttribute("width", "236");
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    y.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="dis" onclick="myFunc()">Click me</button>
<img src="num1.png" style="position:absolute;top:80px;" onclick="myFunction()" />
<div id="myDIV">
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I tried the below code for positioning,but its not working properly.

```
y.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:100px;");  
y.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:-60px;");
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but `margin-left` and `margin-top` are CSS styles, not attributes. Therefore you should use `y.style.marginLeft = '100px';`. Note that I removed the jQuery tag as this is completely unrelated to that. I'd also strongly suggest you give your variables meaningful names. `xy`, `y` etc are all next to useless.

Answer (score 0):

You should access your CSS style property for a DOM element using `style` property, example:

```
y.style.marginLeft = '100px';
y.style.maringTop = '-60px';
```

The `Element.setAttribute()` instead could be used to change an attribute for a DOM element or its value, for example on an `image` you could change the `src` attribute, but `setAttribute` does not work for CSS properties.

```
y.setAttribute("src", "anUrl.png");
```

Edit following your comment:

You can apply a CSS class to your DOM element using, the CSS class will contain the style you want to apply:

`y.classList.add('yourCssClass')`

More information [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: y.style.marginLeft = '100px';
y.style.maringTop = '-60px';

The above code is not working all the time. Instead of that, Is there any possible for positioning the image from CSS.

Comment: @M.Kalidass I made an edit to my answer, showing a possible way how to add a css class to your DOM. Happy coding!